# what could be a deployment strategy with pubspec on dart

Tags: dart

What would be the best way to actually deploy dart code that has pubspec.yaml dependencies? A common thing I've done in the past was to create demos and deploy to github pages. Now that pub uses symbolic links the dependencies do not get pushed to github. Also wondering if this should be a bug to file for pub, being able to deploy with dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We aren't there yet, but pub will in the future support a `deploy` command. That will do things like run dart2js and concatenate/minify your code. It will also physically bring in all of your dependencies so you don't have symlinks. The end result will be a single directory that contains everything your package needs to run.

Comment: Thanks Bob, just testing stuff out with deploying a client app and noticed this limitation.

Comment: Is there a Roadmap document for pub's deploy command?  In particular, are there plans for command-line options to specify input and output directories?

Comment: No, we don't have much of a written roadmap, unfortunately. We tend to be pretty, uh, agile, so we don't write much down in advance. This keeps us nimble but can make it hard to follow along. We don't have plans for specifying the output directory yet, but that would be nice to have. Can you file a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have three options:

- If you already have a server-side technology and a deployment strategy, use that.
- If you're just deploying static stuff, I wonder if Google App Engine would work with these symlinks.
- Heroku supports Dart, although I'm not sure how it supports symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your Dart application on Heroku cloud hosting. There is a step-by-step tutorial [here](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/08/running-dart-in-cloud-with-heroku.html).

It works nice.