# how to deploy dart web app with dart packages?

Tags: dart, dart2js

Consider the following dart web app:

```dart
import "dart:html";
// assume this is a custom library hosted somewhere on github, i.e. 
// there is a pubspec.yaml entry
//
// dependencies:
//    my_hello:
//      git: http://github.com/foo/my_hello.git
//
import "package:my_hello/my_hello.dart" as hello;

main() {
  query("#message").innerHtml = hello.message;
}
```

How to deploy it somewhere on a web server (for example as github pages), such that it can be used as dart based web app in Dartium?

1. Do I have to create a directory `packages` on the web server?
2. Do I have to copy the package `my_hello.dart` to the web server?

   `packages/my_hello/...`

   Or is Dartium able to resolve the dependencies given a `pubspec.yaml` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672090 shows how to configure and use dart2dart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment, you need to deploy the `packages` folders, along with your code.  Dartium doesn't use the `pubspec.yaml`

Currently in progress, there is a `dart2dart` tool, which does a similar thing to `dart2js` - tree shaking, minification, and bringing all the code into a single deployable source file. See this [dartbug issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=8172) for instruction and this [recent discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/misc/TfgSOCyAYNA) on google groups.

This will likely form part of the `pub deploy` scenario, which will be used to package your app for deployment on a web server.

See also: [what could be a deployment strategy with pubspec on dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336685/what-could-be-a-deployment-strategy-with-pubspec-on-dart)
and: [Creating a Javascript deployment set from Dart2js output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143531/creating-a-javascript-deployment-set-from-dart2js-output/15145090#15145090)

**Update**: [Dartbug 6006](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6006) is being worked on at the moment, and says that it work like the following:

> It'll copy everything in "web" into a deploy directory, run dart2dart and dart2js on all the entrypoints, and clean up the Dart source files. This will produce a directory that can be served without any additional steps.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$ pub build [--no-minify]
```

> Use `pub build` when you’re ready to deploy your web app. When you run `pub build`, it generates the assets for the current package and all of its dependencies, putting them into a new directory named build.

From a [Seth Ladd's post on Google+](https://plus.google.com/+SethLadd/posts/ZVw5EFX355z) (no longer available).

Answer (score 2):

Personally I've been using rsync since its simple and fast

```
cd web
rsync -RLr . ../../deploy/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a utiliy script which copies the packages a web app depends on  to a deployment directory - see  [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Gubaer/5099605)