# Test Dart and dart2js code in same page

Tags: javascript, laravel, dart, dart2js

I trying my luck on Dart.
I've got an application that loads the Dart file and the generated Javascript:

```
<script type="application/dart" src="/bones/build/web/quiz/quiz1.dart">
</script>
<script src="/bones/build/web/quiz/quiz1.dart.js">
</script>
```

When I open this page in Dartium, both the Javascript and the Dart code are run (I only need one).
How do I go about to run only the Dart file, and not the Javascript when opened in Dartium, and run the Javascript when opened in Firefox or Chromium?

Should I create two pages, one for Dart and one for Javascript?
That means I'd have to edit two files when I want to change anything. Feels wrong to me.

Kind regards,
Hendrik Jan

---- EDIT ----
I now realise that it might be important that this application is written in PHP using the Laravel framework.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you use server side. The Dart client application is just static content for your server app and connects to your server using HTTP(S) or WebSocket.

Comment: I'm probably not understanding what you are saying. My own solution does not use pub build or pub serve to include the script tags, but uses the dart.js file that handles it for me. See my own answer for what I am using now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following solution that works for me. In stead of linking to the generated Javascript file (as I did in my question), I link to **`dart.js`** which will load the generated Javascript in case Dart is not supported in the browser, like this:

```
<script type="application/dart" src="/bones/build/web/quiz/quiz1.dart">
</script>
<script src="/bones/build/web/packages/browser/dart.js">
</script>
```

This makes it possible for me to see the result of my work in Dartium and also in Firefox and Chromium.

Comment: This is the correct way of doing this.  the dart.js file has all the logic needed to figure out if the Dart VM is supported by the browser and will serve the appropriate version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything, let `pub build`/`pub serve` handle how the script tags are included into the entry page.

The problem is that you can't build deployable Dart code. `dart2dart` is experimental and not yet supported (see [Run Dart WebApp on Apache Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672090) for more details on `dart2dart`).
If you use `pub serve` a Dart capable browser runs the Dart code and a browser that doesn't support Dart runs the code built to JavaScript.

Dartium is also only for development and therefore there is no browser out there that processes Dart code.  As far as I know the Dart team tries to have dart2dart ready when Chrome supports Dart.

But for development using `pub serve` it's just fine and you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into pub build and pub serve. The application is written in PHP (Laravel) and I am not sure how to combine that with the build process. Should have included that in my question, have now added it to my question.